# Amazon EC2 sending GET request from hardware

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2, esp8266

I have an amazon server with some index file which i can load from any browser or from hurl.it get request which is working .

I then try to send that same GET request from some hardware chip .

I create a TCP connection to port 80 , which seems to work and return true value.

Then i am trying to send a GET request which is not responding at all .

Here it is :

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host:52.xx.xxx.xx
User-Agent:runscope/0.1
Content-Type:application/json
Connection:close                 //tried also without this
```

Am i missing something basic here ?
Does EC2 accept my TCP on port 80 ? (  I can see that i get true result but i dont really know that )

Is there a way also on EC2 to see who was connecting to TCP/HTTP? how?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I should have put this here before, but here is my request :

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:xx.x1.2xx.1x\r\nUser-Agent:runscope/0.1\r\nContent-Type:application/json\r\nConnection:close\r\n"
```

Comment: What do your web server logs show? Did the request make it to the web server? If so, are there logs showing why it did not respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HTTP request looks like this

```
 GET /path HTTP/1.0\r\n
 Host: ..\r\n
 \r\n
```

What you are probably missing is the empty line at the end. What you might do wrong too is the line end (must be `\r\n` but several servers accept `\n` too). And if you do only a simple request you should better use `HTTP/1.0` because with `HTTP/1.1` you get several features which makes handling the response harder, like implicit keep-alive and chunked encoding.

Apart from that giving a `Content-type` in a GET request make no sense, since a GET request itself has no content (contrary to POST request).

Comment: Thanks a lot. i actually did put the r\n\ . Please see my edit for the quesiont and let me know if you have nay comments .

Comment: @Curnelious: your edited question shows that you've missed the final single "\r\n", e.g. the empty line after all the HTTP headers. Thus the server is still waiting for the full header before returning the response.

Comment: Thanks,to be honest it was there and i have removed it from the edit... anyway-i did tried that and it didn't worked...

Comment: Well i am sorry for it ! the problem was with the hardware bits... well, hardware is hard! i accepted your answer because its helpful !